# Install vowpalwabbit python wrapper problems

Tags: python, boost, installation, wrapper, vowpalwabbit

I try to install vowpalwabbit python's wrapper.

After exectution:

```
$ brew install libtool autoconf automake
$ brew install boost-python --with-python3
$ pip install vowpalwabbit
```

I got following error:

```
Using Python 3.6
/usr/bin/g++ -std=c++0x -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -I /usr/local/include -I ../rapidjson/include -fPIC -c pylibvw.cc -o pylibvw.o
/usr/bin/g++ -shared  pylibvw.o -L /usr/local/lib -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/config -lpython2.7 -ldl -framework CoreFoundation ../vowpalwabbit/libvw.a ../vowpalwabbit/liballreduce.a -L /usr/local/lib -lboost_program_options-mt -lboost_serialization-mt -l pthread -l z -l boost_python3-mt -o pylibvw.so
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"boost::python::detail::init_module(char const*, void (*)())", referenced from:
    _initpylibvw in pylibvw.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [pylibvw.so] Error 1
make: *** [python] Error 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "/private/var/folders/n6/lhgdgsns3z5gh0q93s3w_dz80000gn/T/pip-build-lesezaxg/vowpalwabbit/setup.py", line 202, in <module>
  tests_require=['tox']
File "/Users/andrei/anaconda/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
  dist.run_commands()
File "/Users/andrei/anaconda/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
  self.run_command(cmd)
File "/Users/andrei/anaconda/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
File "/Users/andrei/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wheel/bdist_wheel.py", line 179, in run
  self.run_command('build')
File "/Users/andrei/anaconda/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
  self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/Users/andrei/anaconda/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
File "/Users/andrei/anaconda/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build.py", line 135, in run
  self.run_command(cmd_name)
File "/Users/andrei/anaconda/lib/python3.6/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
  self.distribution.run_command(command)
File "/Users/andrei/anaconda/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
  cmd_obj.run()
File "/Users/andrei/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py3.6.egg/setuptools/command/build_ext.py", line 77, in run
File "/Users/andrei/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py", line 185, in run
  _build_ext.build_ext.run(self)
File "/Users/andrei/anaconda/lib/python3.6/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 339, in run
  self.build_extensions()
File "/Users/andrei/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/old_build_ext.py", line 193, in build_extensions
  self.build_extension(ext)
File "/private/var/folders/n6/lhgdgsns3z5gh0q93s3w_dz80000gn/T/pip-build-lesezaxg/vowpalwabbit/setup.py", line 113, in build_extension
  subprocess.check_call(['make', 'python'], cwd=path.join(here, 'src'), env=env)
File "/Users/andrei/anaconda/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 291, in check_call
  raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['make', 'python']' returned non-zero exit status 2.
```

I try to run this command with include and exclude anaconda bin from PATH and still got this exeception.

What I am doing wrong?

P.S. [full log](https://pastebin.com/6xX9xKq2)

Comment: My guess is you don't have Boost installed. See https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit#mac-os-x-specific-info

Comment: @MartinPopel Boost installed, so problem is not here